# htmlタグのデフォルトのfont-sizeについて

Tags: html, css

remを使用する際、 `<html>`の font-size が基準になるとのことですが、

**Q1.`<html>`の font-size を明示的に指定した方が良いですか？**
指定しない場合は、ブラウザのデフォルトのfont-size(16px？) が自動的に適用される？

**Q2.`<html>`の font-size はどうやって指定しますか？**
・`<html>`指定に、rem を使用しても良い？　自身と重複しますが影響ありますか？
・`<html>`指定に、em　を使用しても良い？　この場合に親要素は存在しないと思うのですが、影響ありますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q1.の font-size を明示的に指定した方が良いですか？

どちらでも構いません。もしフォントサイズを調整する必要が無いならば必要ありません。

> ・指定に、rem を使用しても良い？　自身と重複しますが影響ありますか？

`html` 要素で `rem` 単位を使用した場合、それは `font-size` プロパティの初期値を基準にして扱われます<sup>[[1]](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#font-relative-lengths)</sup>。親要素の存在しない要素の継承値はプロパティの初期値<sup>[[2]](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#inheriting)</sup>であるため、これは `em` 単位でも同様です。